# Send token from addressA to addressB through contract

Tags: solidity

Hello how can i send a token from the msg.sender to mycontract through a function inside my contract?

1. i tried to do a transferFrom
   "`IERC20(old_tokenAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), query_oldBalance(msg.sender));`"  but i get:  `execution reverted: ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance` even if i put
   the allowance to a much bigger number of what im trying to transfer,
2. if i try with a normal transfer `IERC20(old_tokenAddress).transfer(address(this), query_oldBalance(msg.sender));` i get : `"execution reverted: Transfer amount exceeds the maxTxAmount.` same here i tried to set the maxtxamount to a much bigger number than the token im trying to transfer.
   Just to clarify the function *query_oldBalance* is a function that return `IERC20(old_tokenAddress).balanceOf(_address);`
   Hope someone can help me, ty.

Comment: We require that the code be working correctly, to the best of the author's knowledge, before proceeding with a review. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`IERC20(_tokenAddress).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), old_balance);` was right but before call this func the user should approve the **address** of the **new** token **ON** the **old** token contract